# Assigning existing entity to Many-to-Many does not update one side

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to test the following:

```
// Arrange
var alpha = new Alpha { Name = "Hello" };
var beta = new Beta { Name = "World" };

using (var t = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    this.Session.Save(alpha);
    this.Session.Save(beta);
    t.Commit();
}

// Act
using (var t = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var a = this.Session.Get<Alpha>(1);
    var b = this.Session.Load<Beta>(1);

    a.Betas.Add(b);

    t.Commit();
}

// Assert
//// this succeeds
Assert.AreEqual(1, this.Session.Get<Alpha>(1).Betas.Count, "Alpha contains beta");
//// this fails
Assert.AreEqual(1, this.Session.Get<Beta>(1).Alphas.Count, "Beta contains alpha");  fails here
Assert.AreEqual(1, this.Session.Query<Beta>().Count(), "Only one beta");
```

My mappings are

```
public AlphaMap()
{
    this.Id(a => a.Id);
    this.Map(a => a.Name);
    this.HasManyToMany(a => a.Betas)
        .Cascade.All()
        .Table("AlphaBetas")
        .ParentKeyColumn("AlphaId")
        .ChildKeyColumn("BetaId");
}
```

and

```
public BetaMap()
{
    this.Id(a => a.Id);
    this.Id(a => a.Name);
    this.HasManyToMany(a => a.Alphas)
        .Cascade.All()
        .Inverse()
        .Table("AlphaBetas")
        .ParentKeyColumn("BetaId")
        .ChildKeyColumn("AlphaId");
}
```

I'm unsure as to why the Beta side of the Many-to-Many relationship is not being updated. Could somebody please explain it to me - I'm a NH novice so am probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is, that the second relation is not set in C#. We can see just: `a.Betas.Add(b);`. And these objects are still in a session. So the tests are done on top of in-memory still kept objects.

Call the `session.Clear()` before the Assertion and the latest data will be loaded... correctly assigned from boths sides.

*NOTE: Also be careful with these Cascade settings on many-to-many. They do not effect the pairing table... they do effect the other end*

Comment: Ah doing `session.Clear()` works! In terms of implementing a Unit Of Work pattern, should one always call clear after `Commit`ing changes?

Comment: I would say: yes. Exactly this is what we have to do. One operation for write... clean... other for read! exactly. Enjoy NHiberante ;)